# SSIS, dealing with codepages, unicode

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ssis

I have a database where most strings are stored in varchar columns.
One column stores peoples names and some have an apostrophe, e.g. "O'Malley".

When i output this data to csv, the apostrophe becomes "Oâ€™ Malley".

I have tried a number of steps but cannot get this resolved and could use some advice. So far i have:

- Converted all strings to Unicode.
- Changed the codepages on the ssis tasks(oledb source, script tasks & flat file connector to 65001
- changed the "unicode" property for the flat file destination connection to "True". This ruined the csv as now when opened in excel, all data is in the 1st column, excel cant see that it is a delimited file.

Any advise on what to try next?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you observing this strange character in? Excel? Notepad? Can you confirm this is a `varchar` field, not a `nvarchar` field? What does the SSIS metadata viewer say the datatype is? If you open your CSV in notepad++ what type of encoding is it?

Comment: I'm seeing the unwanted chars in excel, but if opened in notepad, the data looks normal, without the unwanted chars

Comment: So this is an excel problem. Does this help: https://scrapehero.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/5000617795-how-to-open-csv-files-that-have-unicode-unprintable-or-weird-looking-characters-in-excel. If the objective is to have a file that can be opened in excel, then try an excel target (not a CSV target)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this. Data is loaded into csv without any error, tell me if I am missing something I will update the answer accordingly.

Code Page: 1252 (ANSI - Latin I)

Database Table contains **Table:** Emp
**columns:** Id INT, 
 Name VARCHAR(200)
[image]

Flat file destination properties are:

[image]

Here is the snapshot of file in excel

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking, the unwanted chars only appear if I open the cache in excel, but are not present if I open the csv in notepad.